# Android Studio: migration to AndroidX with third-party

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I followed the official migration: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

The migration worked perfectly.

In my project, I use several third libraries. The complete build of my entire project works.

BUT now from Android Studio, I have a lot of syntax errors (from the editor, not after the build!). ie with the third-party "advrecyclerview" where the property "itemView" doesn't know now because:

[image]

So how can I change editor syntax analysis, etc. have you got some solutions?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please dont post code as images

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are using the wrong recycler view.

If you follow the [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) you posted, you will see the new package should be

```
androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
```

(which means androidx.recyclerview in imports)

You need to make sure to change the XML to match

---

**Edit**

As it is in a library, make sure to enable Jetifier to auto-fix the libraries. It can still fail, but it does a good job for the majority.

You need to put the following `gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

More information on this is in the [migration document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: the problem is not in my code, but into the third-library code

Comment: Ok, so you need the jetifier flags if you dont have them, ill update my answer

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, I found the problem: from Android Studio, I did "Invalide Caches and Restart", and the editor syntax works perfectly now.